# Returning data to the original process that invoke a subprocess

Tags: python-2.7, wxpython, subprocess, python-multithreading

Someone told me to post this as a new question. This is a follow up to 
[Instantiating a new WX Python GUI from spawn thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10679134/instantiating-a-new-wx-python-gui-from-spawn-thread)

I implemented the following code to a script that gets called from a spawned thread (Thread2)

```
# Function that gets invoked by Thread #2
def scriptFunction():
  # Code to instantiate GUI2; GUI2 contains wx.TextCtrl fields and a 'Done' button
  p = subprocess.Popen("python secondGui.py", bufsize=2048, shell=True,stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

  # Wait for a response
  p.wait()

  # Read response
  response = p.stdout.read()

  # Process entered data
  processData()
```

On the new process running GUI2, I want the 'Done' button event handler to return 4 data sets to Thread2, and then destroy itself (GUI2)

```
def onDone(self,event):
  # This is the part I need help with; Trying to return data back to main process that instantiated this GUI (GUI2)
  process = subprocess.Popen(['python', 'MainGui.py'], shell=False, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
  print process.communicate('input1', 'input2', 'input3', 'input4')

  # kill GUI
  self.Close()
```

Currently, this implementation spawns another Main GUI in a new process. What I want to do is return data back to the original process. Thanks.

Comment: Are you saying the data isn't coming back to the calling thread or that you can't get the thread itself to pass the data back?

Comment: Apparently because I am new, I cannot post the solution I have found. I will post my complete solution later, once the require 8hrs wait has pass, but here is the my quick and dirty implementation. Its not the most elegant, but it meets my needs.

Comment: The function that gets invoked by Thread #2 has string parser to breakup the concatenated 4 data set response.

The event handler packages the 4 words into a string to return back to main process (Thread2)
      sys.stdout.write('input1' + " " + 'input2' + " " + 'input3' + " " + 'input4')

If anybody else has a cleaner way, I am still open to suggestions. Thanks.

Comment: You could use string substitution "%s %s %s %s" % (input1...input4) or use something like pickle.

Answer (score 0):

Do the two scripts have to be separate? I mean, you can have multiple frames running on one main loop and transfer information between the two using pubsub: http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/06/27/wxpython-and-pubsub-a-simple-tutorial/

Theoretically, what you're doing should work too. Other methods I've heard of involve using Python's socket server library to create a really simple server that runs that the two programs can post to and read data from. Or a database or watching a directory for file updates.

Comment: Thanks Mike, Ill take a look at that. I didn't implement it that way. I was working on an Answer post, but got stop with an 8hr require wait limit because I am new to the site. I will look into it and post the solution I am currently using so others can check it out.

Answer (score 0):

Function that gets invoked by Thread #2

```
def scriptFunction():
  # Code to instantiate GUI2; GUI2 contains wx.TextCtrl fields and a 'Done' button
  p = subprocess.Popen("python secondGui.py", bufsize=2048, shell=True,stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

  # Wait for a response
  p.wait()

  # Read response and split the return string that contains 4 word separated by a comma
  responseArray = string.split(p.stdout.read(), ",")

  # Process entered data
  processData(responseArray)
```

'Done' button event handler that gets invoked when the 'Done' button is clicked on GUI2

```
def onDone(self,event):
  # Package 4 word inputs into string to return back to main process (Thread2)
  sys.stdout.write("%s,%s,%s,%s" % (dataInput1, dataInput2, dataInput3, dataInput4))

  # kill GUI2
  self.Close()
```

Thanks for your help Mike!